# Database returning zero rows

Tags: sql

I have been having some trouble running SQLi queries in PHP, so I went to the database directly through PHP Admin and even when I run the most basic of queries such as the example below I am getting an empty results set.

Is there any reason why this could happen?

```
SELECT 'fname' FROM 'participants' WHERE 'sname' = 'Jones';
```

Comment: I should add that I have double checked that the values exist as stated in the database table and that the column names are right.

Comment: You have single quotes where they are not needed.  Do not use single quotes for identifiers.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had error reporting enabled, you'd see that your query throws an error because you are using `'` instead of backticks ` for your table and column names.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT `fname` FROM `participants` WHERE `sname` = 'Jones';
```